Installing concurrent package to handle exceptions in parallel
I am trying to catch warnings as exceptions in a function running in parallel. According to this post, the concurrent package is well-suited to error-handling in parallelised functions (I first tried joblib, but this did not perform as expected). However, I am not able to install concurrent.
I have created a conda environment with python 3.8.18 and tried both conda install concurrent and pip install concurrent, but both were unsuccessful. I cannot find concurrent on either conda or pip list of available packages. How can I install concurrent in my conda environment?

This is part of the Python standard library.

Correct way py -m pip install concurrently

Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.
